# Training a model in python

Tags: python, model, training-data

I am trying to learn how to build a model and train it on training set. I have done this using MultinomialNB before in Python but not I am trying to build a custom model using a set of equations. Can someone please lead me in right direction? Thank you for your help.

So when I train the model with MultinomialNB, I use the following code.

clf=MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(xtrain, ytrain)

What I am trying to do now involves an equation for tag prediction A_i where i is the tag I am predicting for a given posts. I am not sure how to go about training a model using this equation A_i.

Comment: You should add some more information into this question. Show some code too where you have tried to make a model. Right now there's not enough information to help you.

Comment: Much better, Someone might be able to help you now hopefully.